# django get values from a related model (foreignkey)

Tags: django, django-views, foreign-key-relationship

In home (views.py) how to display a list of all exercises (name and repetitions) linked to the same user Card?

#### models.py

```
class Card(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User)
    trainer = models.ForeignKey(User, related_name='trainer')
    def __unicode__(self):
        return u'%s' % (self.id)




class Exercise(models.Model):
    card = models.ForeignKey(Card)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    repetitions = models.IntegerField(default=0, blank=True, null=True)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return u'%s' % (self.name)
```

#### views.py

```
from django.http import HttpResponse
from django.contrib.auth.decorators import login_required
from cards.models import Card, Exercise

@login_required
def home(request):
    user = request.user.get_full_name()      
    return HttpResponse("Welcome %s This is your home." % (user))
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I never give up and finally I fix it. I tried it and it works.

```
@login_required
def home(request):
    user = request.user.get_full_name() 

    exercises = Exercise.object.filter(card__user=request.user)

    html = []
    for k in exercises:
        html.append('<tr><td>%s - %s</td></tr>' % (k.name, k.repetitions))
    return HttpResponse('Welcome %s This is your home.<br/><table>%s</table>' % (user, '\n'.join(html)))
```

Comment: I used it but I get this: [, , ] 

what does it means?

(note that my Exercise model contains other fields not only name and repetitions)

Comment: yes I should have because I put some using admin interface. Anyway how can I check if I have exercises data there?

Comment: I get this:
Welcome Fabrizio Avantaggiato This is your home. [, , ] (ops you changed the response wait alittle bit)

I use HttpResponse because from the moment I'm learning the django/python side, I want to understand that first, I will concentrate on rendering a template after.

Comment: ok I get this:

Welcome Fabrizio Avantaggiato This is your home. [{'repetitions': 30, 'name': u'bicipiti'}, {'repetitions': 10, 'name': u'tricipiti'}, {'repetitions': 0, 'name': u'panca'}]

now how to isolate each value and display that in a list (without all that brackets)? is render_to_response needed?

Comment: can we use render instead? how to use it?

Comment: instead of using a pre formatted list, is it possible to get each value from the exercises tuple and display it one by one? How can I solve this problem?

Comment: thank you catherine, I solved with render_to_response and template tags that get values from exercises =  [{'repetitions': 30, 'name': u'bicipiti'}, {'repetitions': 10, 'name': u'tricipiti'}, {'repetitions': 0, 'name': u'panca'}] - I will accept your answer anyway, thank you!

Comment: welcome, I never give up on your question because I never done it before and I want to know if it is possible in HttpResponse :)